# Showing a continuous function does not converge uniformly without use of the maximum on a closed bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So we all know we can show $f_{n}(x)=nx^{n}(1-x)$ does not converge uniformly on $\left[0,1\right]$ by showing that $\max\left[|f_{n}-f|:x\in[0,1]\right]$does not go to zero. In order to do this we have to argue that the sequence of $f_{n}$'s are all polynomials and thus differentiable.

What I'm looking for is a different way to do this, by showing

$\exists \epsilon>0$ $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ $|f_{n}-f|\geq \epsilon$ $\forall n \geq N$

It gets down to picking an $\epsilon$ which is smaller than $|nx^{n}(1-x)|$ for a value of $x$ in terms of $N$, however, choosing it is elusive to me. I was also not sure if we could make use of an integral here as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each fixed $x \in [0,1]$ we have $f_n(x) \to 0$. You have to show
$$\exists \varepsilon_0 > 0,\ \forall N\in\mathbb{N},\ \exists n\geqslant N,\ \exists x \in [0,1] \colon\ |f_n(x)| \geqslant \varepsilon_0.$$

Let $\varepsilon_0 := \frac{1}{2e}$. For arbitrary $N$ put $n := N$ and $x := \frac{N}{N+1}$. Then
$$f_n(x) = N\left(\frac{N}{N+1}\right)^N \left(1-\frac{N}{N+1}\right) = \left(\frac{N}{N+1}\right)^{N+1} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{N+1}{N}\right)^{N+1}} = \dfrac{1}{\left(1+\frac1N\right)^N\left(1+\frac1N\right)} > \frac{1}{2e}.$$

Comment: How are you getting that? I'm just getting $f_{N}=\left(\frac{N}{N+1}\right)^{1+N}$

Comment: @DavidSacco, added to the answer.

Comment: gotcha, nice answer.